# Corebird twitter client for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: twitter

I have recently installed ubuntu on my laptop (wubi method) and I'm very pleased. All and all it does everything that I need, but recently I heard about [corebird](http://corebird.baedert.org/) - a twitter client that looks spot on. I have been searching but I couldn't find how to install it on ubuntu 14.04. Can you help me doing so?

I have tried other twitter clients like hotot, turpial and birdie, but I don't like them that much.

Thanks in advance, cheers!

**EDIT**
I have finally installed valac. However, there is another problem with gtk+-3.12.0. After typing ./configure, I get:

configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.39.5    atk >= 2.7.5    pango >= 1.32.4    cairo >= 1.12.0    cairo-gobject >= 1.12.0    gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.27.1) were not met:

No package 'pango' found
No package 'cairo' found
No package 'cairo-gobject' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BASE_DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS
and BASE_DEPENDENCIES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Comment: There isn't a ppa or .deb for it. You will have to compile it yourself. I personally cannot guide you, but you will find the code here: https://github.com/baedert/corebird

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's now a PPA that contains Corebird packages, available for Ubuntu 14.10 and Ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/corebird

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install corebird
```

Ubuntu 14.04 user also need Gnome3 and Gnome 3 Staging PPA for the dependencies:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

via: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/07/install-corebird-ubuntu-ppa/
PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/corebird

Answer (score 2):

Download `corebird` from github: [this](https://github.com/baedert/corebird) is the project page, where you can find information about dependencies and installation instructions, and [this](https://github.com/baedert/corebird/archive/master.zip) is the link to source.

Download sourcefile in  Desktop, then  type:

```
cd ~/Desktop
unzip corebird-master.zip
cd corebird-master
```

make sure you have all program needed: install with:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf autopoint automake intltool libtool
```

now,configure corebird with:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

Probably there will be some unmet dependencies, you will need to install via `sudo apt-get install`. Type:

```
sudo apt-get install librest-dev libjson-glib-dev libsqlite3-dev libsoup2.4-dev intltool libgee-dev libvala-0.22-dev libglib2.0-dev automake libgee-0.8-dev
```

If the version of gtk is not correct, you will need to install the latest libraries by downloading [this package](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gtk+/3.12/gtk+-3.12.0.tar.xz).
Download in Desktop, then type:

```
cd ~/Desktop
tar xfv gtk+-3.12.0.tar.xz
cd ~/Desktop/gtk+-3.12.0/    
./configure 
make (this will take a while)
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Check also valac version, typing:

```
valac --version
```

if version in minor than 0.24.0, then you have to install also vala 0.24: so download source from [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Release#Vala_0.24.0) ([this](http://download.gnome.org/sources/vala/0.24/vala-0.24.0.tar.xz) is then link to file)
download source in Desktop, then type:

```
tar xfv ~/Desktop/vala-0.24.0.tar.xz
cd ~/Desktop/vala-0.24.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

if everything is ok, you will now be able to install codebird.
When all dependencies will be installed rerun the  `autogen` command, and if the configuration is successful, type:

```
make
sudo make install
```

You can now use the newly installed corebird.

Comment: The OP seems to be a pretty new user, would be better if you could explain how to install those dependencies, it does not seem to be easy.

Comment: @Jobin absolutely. But it depends on which packages should be installed. I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @girardengo . As I said, I'm still learning and I'm having a few issues. I downloaded the zip file but how do I do that "cd /path/to/corebird-master"? Should I type it on archive manager, or elsewhere? And how do I configure it with that code?

Comment: @girardengo I did it but there is a problem. I have installed those packages, after typing autogen again I get: "src/Makefile.am:13: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
src/Makefile.am:13:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
src/Makefile.am:13:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
src/Makefile.am:13:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
src/Makefile.am:13:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1"
-and after make: "make: *** No rule to make target `install'. Stop." so..?

Comment: @jimpinho I edited my answer with more details. You should be able to solve this problem by running the command apt-get added to the beginning of the procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @girardengo. It's been a while, but I have been away. There is a problem though, I have edited my question.