# Installing Gtk+ >= 3.12 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gtk3

I'm just trying to install [Corebird](https://github.com/baedert/corebird). It has some dependencies and one of them is Gtk+ >= 3.12. I would say I have search a lot and finally frustrated [from a lot of other dependencies](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-building.html). I'm afraid if Corebird worth it finally or not!

Is there a straight-forward way to install GTK+ 3.12 on my Ubuntu PC? I mean step-by-step tutorial!

Comment: There are similar question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/462521/corebird-twitter-client-for-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: The same problems exists in this solution. It just is repeating all other solutions. Compiling gtk+ needs some other packages which I can't find them.

Comment: Question header is about `gtk`, solution is about corebird. Can we fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has already been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462521/corebird-twitter-client-for-ubuntu-14-04). Corebird packages are now available.

If you're on Ubuntu 14.04, open terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Then, for both 14.04 and 14.10 flavours, type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/corebird

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install corebird
```

Finally, remove gnome 3 staging ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/07/install-corebird-ubuntu-ppa/

Comment: well done! it works. just why should I remove gnome 3 staging ppa?

Comment: @Omid If you don't remove gnome3-staging your Software Updater might give you a "partial update" error, which would be hazardous. It is strongly advised not to keep that ppa.

Comment: Hrm, when installing last step, corebird, I received "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 corebird : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.11.2) but 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: Hrm, seems as if I confused libgtk for gtk+. At any rate, the source link has a comment with the same issue and one suggestion to `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0` doesn't work as it is still an older version, and "up to date".

Comment: Actually, I didn't add the gnome3-staging repo. I copied both lines in the beginning but had an error so just tried the first line and forgot to re-run with staging. corebird installed correctly, without having to install libgtk-3-0 since it figured out the dependency correctly.

Answer (score -2):

You can download `libgtk3-0-3.12` .deb file ftom [Launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/testing/+build/5908666/+files/libgtk-3-0_3.12.1-0ubuntu1%7Etrusty1_amd64.deb).

Then install that file with the command :

```
sudo dpkg -i {.DEB FILE NAME HERE]
```

Comment: link: page not found

Comment: You may be able to find a updated link here https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/testing/+packages