# How do I add a PPA in a libertine container?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-touch, ppa, libertine

I am trying to install Corebird ([Corebird twitter client for Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462521/corebird-twitter-client-for-ubuntu-14-04)) in a libertine container named `vivid` on my M10 tablet. After adding the PPA's, which do show up in `~/.cache/libertine-container/vivid/rootfs/etc/apt/sources.list.d` the package still won't install.

I have tried:

```
libertine-container-manager install-package -d vivid -p corebird
```

And from within a shell ([Access git in libertine container](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781768/access-git-in-libertine-container/781781#781781)) inside the container:

```
apt-get install
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it might not be possible to do this yet.

From going through `libertine-container-manager --help` I think the command should be

```
libertine-container-manager configure -a "ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/corebird" -i vivid
```

The equivalent of `apt-get update` is just

```
libertine-container-manager update -i vivid
```

You'll find this and more with `libertine-container-manager --help`.

However when I execute the first command I get the following error:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ libertine-container-manager configure -a "ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/corebird" -i vivid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 321, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 91, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 87, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 101, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 151, in urlopen
    capath=capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 437, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 119, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 837, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 382, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 346, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 333, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 292, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
    lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 87, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 101, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 151, in urlopen
    capath=capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 437, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thank you for the correct syntax. That part works for me, now I'm looking for the equivalent of apt-get update. I think the error you got is due to the fact that the default libertine container isn't writable.

Comment: Ah. I had tried in my vivid container too but it didn't work. I must try again later. I tried with different ppa's and the default container just to double check syntax errors -> that's the output I incorrectly pasted above.

The equivalent of apt-get update should be

Comment: Well, I'm a bit further on the proper commands now. Unfortunately the package still can't be located. Pointers to log files are welcome.

Comment: So you don't get the errors that I do? That's interesting, could you link to a paste of what your output is?

Comment: Yeah, I should have kept the output but I didn't, sorry about that. I can't repeat the package addition, it just returned:
`ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/corebird already added in container.`

Comment: Add another ppa? You could remove it afterwards?

Comment: This is what I get: `~$ libertine-container-manager configure -a "ppa:ci-train-ppa-service/stable-phone-overlay" -i vivid
gpg: keyring '/tmp/tmpznsrykv2/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring '/tmp/tmpznsrykv2/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key ECF1204C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpznsrykv2/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key ECF1204C: public key "Launchpad PPA for CI Train PPA Service Team" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK`

Comment: "Unfortunately the package still can't be located." ok,  does that just mean that there isn't an arm build available? Sounds like it might. Can we test with a ppa and app that would be available in arm?

Comment: I'm giving up on this one for now. Nice learning experience, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: You too. If I test it during the week I will update.

Comment: Hey Jack, have you found a solution? I tried a different workaround which gave some more error output. http://askubuntu.com/questions/826110/how-to-install-seafile-within-libertine-container